# convert the Address into Latitude and Longitude for Google Maps in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, geocoding

How to convert the Address into Latitude and Longitude in Objective C?
I want to use Google Maps over there i iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Geocoding.  If you are using Google Maps, they provide [their own geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding).

For a detailed explanation of doing this on the iPhone, with code examples, see this blog post by Björn Sållarp:

- [iPad/iPhone forward geocoding API using Google gecoding service](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/)